# Call asp.net core web api from PostMan

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to call following function (asp.net web api core) from PostMan:

```
[HttpPost]
public InfluencerSearchResultWithFacets Post(string q, string group, List<string> subGroups)
{
   return GetSearchResult("",null,null);
}
```

But I get following error:
A non-empty request body is required

I have setup PostMan like this:
[image]

[image]

I also tried adding to body:
[image]

Comment: You're doing a `HttpPost`, you should put the parameters in the body, not in the url.

Comment: or the Headers...

Comment: You can also try tagging your parameters with `[FromUri]`.

Comment: I tried all combinations. Also putting the parameters in the body. I have added that too. I add an image to main post witnin 30 secs.

Comment: I tried adding it in all tabs now :D But another error when adding to body. Can't the values be empty?

Comment: Wondering if it is because of the array (subGroups). I can see there only is a File or Text type.

Comment: Since you are passing a list `subGroups[0]` value `Music`. Or construct the body in raw with json.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you can create a model like

```
public class Model
{
  public string q { get; set; }
  public string group { get; set; }
  public List<string>subGroups { get; set; }
}
```

and use it

```
[HttpPost]
public InfluencerSearchResultWithFacets Post([FromBody] Model model)
{
   return GetSearchResult("",null,null);
}
```

[image]

This is if you fit Json format.
Also you can leave some parameters in URL and other pass as a body like

```
[HttpPost]
public InfluencerSearchResultWithFacets Post([FromUri]string q, [FromUri]string group, [FromBody]List<string> subGroups)
{
   return GetSearchResult("",null,null);
}
```

[image]