# How to allow an empty request body for a reference type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net-core, get, postman

I'm Building an .Net Core api controller, I would like to allow users to send `GET` requests with or without the `MyRequest` class as a parameter, so the calling the method with `Get(null)` for example will be Ok.

`GET api/myModels` requests method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Get(MyRequest myRequest)
{
    if (myRequest == null)
        myRequest = new myRequest();

    var result = this._myService.Get(myRequest.Filters, myRequest.IncludeProperties);
    return Ok(result);     
}
```

`MyRequest` class:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Filters { get; set; }
    public string IncludeProperties { get; set; }
}
```

When I refer to this `Get` method using `Postman` with Body, it works.
The problem is, when I keep the body empty (to call the Get method with a `MyRequest` null object as a parameter like `Get(null)`) I'm getting this `Postman`'s massage of:

> "A non-empty request body is required."

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462958/call-asp-net-core-web-api-from-postman?rq=1), but there, the parameters are value type.

Comment: What's inside `this._myService.Get` method? You either need to handle empty request inside `_myService.Get` method or create `_myService.Get` method overload without `Filters` and  `IncludeProperties` parameters.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do this:

```
  services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
  {
       options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
  });
```

Comment: This one should be selected as correct solution. Previous answer doesn't work.

Comment: Same thing can be used in `services.AddControllers(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MvcOptions> configure)`

Answer (score 4):

You can make it a optional parameter by assigning a default value `null` and specifying explicitly that the values will be coming as part of request url

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Get([FromQuery]MyRequest myRequest = null)
{
```

BTW, a `GET` operation has no body and thus all the endpoint parameter should be passed through query string (Or) as Route value.

You should specify a routing in your api end point and have the values passed through route and querystring. something like

```
[HttpGet("{IncludeProperties}")]
//[Route("{IncludeProperties}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Get(string IncludeProperties = null, IEnumerable<string> Filters = null)
{
```

With the above in place now you can request your api like

```
GET api/myModels?Filters=
```

Comment: What's the difference between having a `Get()` method with default parameter value, or calling with `Get(null)`? The result will be the same _"A non-empty request body is required."_ cause OP is passing that `request` values to some `this._myService.Get` method, which is probably returning above error.

Comment: @SᴇM, Difference? Yes what if you want to get all data with no filters (in this case)?

Comment: @Rahul I'm just saying that, calling `Get(null)` and `Get()` with default parameter are same. That will not resolve OP's problem.

Comment: @ShaharShokrani see edit in answer. the last part in specific if that helps

Comment: Thanks it works, but please edit the answer to `[FromQuery]`